# Aggregating Sum for two years in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, aggregate

This table contains Policy No, Date and Premium paid on that date:

```
Policy No   Date       Premium 
-------------------------------
ABC         1-Jan-20    $100 
ABC         1-Feb-19    $343 
XYZ         4-Aug-17     $78 
XYZ         3-Sep-15     $56 
XYZ        19-Feb-19     $98 
.         .  
.         .  
.         .
```

We need to find Policy No wise, Date Wise Premium paid for last two years on the given date.

Sample Output:

```
Policy No    Date         Premium 
 -------------------------------
ABC         1-Jan-20      $443
ABC         1-Feb-19      $343 
XYZ         4-Aug-17      $134 
XYZ         3-Sep-15      $56 
XYZ         19-Feb-19     $232
.            .            .
.            .
```

Comment: Is this a rolling 2 year window or everything from within the last two years based on the current date, or something else entirely?

Comment: You've told us what you need, so what have you tried? Why didn't it work, or what about the research you performed didn't you udnerstand?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this if the rolling amount is the sum of the previous 2 years of payments on the particular date of the current payment:

```
select a.[Policy No], a.[Date], sum(b.Premium) as amount from
payment a,
payment b join a on a.[Policy No] = b.[Policy No] and
    a.[Date] >= dateadd(year, -2, b.[Date])
group by a.[Policy No], a.[Date]
```